# Error when clicking like button in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to add a like button to a blog post in Django, but I see this error every time I try to click in the like button. But if I opened the admin page then return to the site, it works properly, and I don't know why that is. Any help please?

The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError at /like/45 Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000001BF06424F10>>
```

views code:

```py
def LikeView(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
```

models code:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes= models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='blog_post')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.About, name='blog-about'),
    path('like/<int:pk>',LikeView,name='like_post'),
]
```

The button in the template:

```html
<form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" , method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button
      type="submit"
      ,
      name="post_id"
      ,
      value="{{ post.id }}"
      ,
      class="btn btn-primary btn-ms"
    >
      Like
    </button>
```

Comment: Your user did not log in.

Comment: I added a @login_reqired before the Likes view and it is works but not completely

Comment: when i click in the like buttom while i'm logged out it takes me to the login in page but after logging in it gave me a page error which say `No Post matches the given query.`                                                      and `The current path, like/44/, matched the last one. `   but if i changed the 'like' path to  `path('/like/<int:pk>',LikeView,name='like_post')` by putting ' / ' before like/  everyting works fine